# Adding Element to Sample Web Page

Tags: html, web, forms-authentication

I'm fairly new to this, but I have a question and hoping someone here might be able to help. My challenge is, I am given a link to a sample checkout page to add some elements into with a provided API key. However I am not sure, how to make the change to the original html file without having access to the back-end server where it resides. How do I access the html for the page to make the necessary changes?

Thank you in advance for any help, you might be able to provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to the machine that is "serving" your HTML pages, you cannot edit the website visible on the internet. Usually you'll have some form of access through a webhost's control panel, or FTP.

It's unclear from your question what the API key is - but it sounds like this may be a form of credential to access the back-end server. In which case you'll need to find out exactly how they expect you utilise the API key.